# SQL Query to retrieve data joining same table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table and data like below.
ID is distinct for each record, recno is record number which goes multiple status changes as below table. I need to query recno which are in error status and never go to closed status. From below sample data I should get recno 3 as result since record 1 and 2 has error status but those have closed status.

```
**ID    recno   status**
1   1   Started
2   1   inProgress
3   1   released
4   1   error
5   1   closed
6   2   Started
7   2   inProgress
8   2   released
9   2   error
10  2   error
11  2   Closed
12  3   Started
13  3   inProgress
14  3   released
15  3   error
```

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last status, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.recno = t.recno);
```

If you want the ones that are in error status:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.recno = t.recno) and
      t.status = 'error';
```

Note:  In most databases and even in some versions of Sybase, you can use `row_number()` for this query as well.  However, not all versions of Sybase support window functions.